# Debian 10 kernel header package version mismatch

Tags: debian, kernel

I install linux-headers-4.19.0-16-amd64 on Debian 10 running the kernel from package linux-image-4.19.0-16-amd64.

I try to build WANPIPE driver from Sangoma and find in /lib/modules/4.19.0-16-amd64/build/Makefile

```
VERSION = 2
PATCHLEVEL = 6
MAKEARGS := -C /usr/src/linux-headers-4.19.0-16-common O=/usr/src/linux-headers-4.19.0-16-amd64
MAKEFLAGS += --no-print-directory
```

So it makes the Setup script of WANPIPE driver thinks it's a 2.6 kernel.

Any hint about why Makefile is so or it's just a bug?

Thanks

edit:

The package linux-headers-4.19.0-16-amd64 contains

/usr/src/linux-headers-4.19.0-16-amd64/Makefile

and there's a symlink

/lib/modules/4.19.0-16-amd64/build -> /usr/src/linux-headers-4.19.0-16-amd64

And, linux-headers-4.19.0-16-common has

/usr/src/linux-headers-4.19.0-16-common/Makefile

/lib/modules/4.19.0-16-amd64/source -> /usr/src/linux-headers-4.19.0-16-common

What are /lib/modules/(version)/source & /lib/modules/()/build are meant for?

Comment: This package isn't complete without its dependency: linux-headers-4.19.0-1-common_4.19.12-1_all.deb . You'll see the correct version gets pulled from its dependency when using a correctly behaving external module.

Comment: Hi @A.B. Thanks for your comment. I have both packages linux-headers-4.19.0-16-amd64 & linux-headers-4.19.0-16-common. Both have top level Makefile. As you said, the Makefile in -common package has correct info. However this Makefile is symlink to /lib/modules/4.19.0-16-amd64/source/Makefile. I wonder why Debian has this.